# The current path, POST, didn't match any of these

Tags: python

So, I have a code below:

> `newEra/urls.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
    
    
    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path("",include('mentor.urls')),]
```

> mentor/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
    
    urlpatterns = [
        path('',views.home_page),
    ]
```

> my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .models import *
from .forms import *

def home_page(request):
    todo = ToDo.objects.all()
    form = ToDoForms()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ToDoForms(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('')


    context = {'todo' : todo, 'form':form}
    return render(request, 'home.html',context)
```

> home.html

```
    <h1>To-Do list</h1>
    
    <form action="POST" method="/">
     {% csrf_token %}
     {{form.name}}
     <input type="submit" value="Create task" >
    </form>
    
    
    <ul>
    {% for to in todo %}
     <li>{{ to }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

But I am getting this error below

> **Using the URLconf defined in NewEra.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
>
> 1. admin/
> 2. 
>
> The current path, POST, didn't match any of these.**

'mentor' file added to the SETTINGS

Answer (score 1):

URLs are regexes. 
Try:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('^/$',views.home_page),
]
```

Comment: Using the URLconf defined in NewEra.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
admin/
^/$
The empty path didn't match any of these.

Comment: How did I miss that:
    <form action="POST" method="/">
Did you mean:
    <form action="/" method="POST">

Comment: ohh Man, I see, I got it, Yeah that's what I meant, Thank you so much